# Fractional Derivatives of $e^{ax}$

Tags: fractional-calculus

We know that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$

$$ D^{n }e^{a x} = a^{n}e^{a x}$$

So I thought that the fractional derivative of this function would be

$$ D^{\alpha }e^{a x} = a^{\alpha}e^{a x}$$

for $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

However, there are different definitions for fractional derivatives and with the typical fractional derivative (Liouville) this is not the case, it uses the incomplete Gamma fnction. So, I would like to know if there are any definition in which

$$ D^{\alpha }e^{a x} = a^{\alpha}e^{a x}$$

holds.

Thank you very much.